# How to get the Transaction ID or relate message with Dialogic DSI library in C?

Tags: c, network-programming, distributed-system, signaling

I'm working with DSI library from Dialogic, which is used for networking programming. I'm using C, in a project where in the phase I'm right now, I need to get IDP messages and ETC messages from a SIGTRAN connection, and then identify to which IDP corresponds every ETC. I know that I can relate those messages using the Transaction ID, as I do it in Wireshark when filtering the messages by otid and dtid. But with the DSI libraries I can't find the way to do it.

I've already searched in the manuals and didn't found a function for getting the transaction ID. In the Dialogic forums did not found a solution too.

Does DSI makes this relationship between messages in other way? How can I tell that an ETC corresponds to an specific IDP?

I'm using INTU for my code, so I have access to the INAP layer. I'm using an HDR structure for the messages.

What I need is to identify no balance calls, so I need the ETC for balance information and IDP for getting the calling party number and called party number and other information. If there is another way to make this relationship without the need of getting the transaction ID, it would be of great use.

Thanks in advance for any help you could give!